# Working on ArrayList in Java, I'm not sure why the loop isn't working

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to add 100 to each elements of the list using a for loop

I saved the desired values (from the list +100)to a variable a; then replace each element of the list using the index and the variable a;

```
List<Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(8);
        numbers.add(9);
        numbers.add(22);
        numbers.add(42);
        numbers.add(100);

for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++){
            int a=numbers.get(i)+100;
            numbers.add(i,a);
       }

        System.out.println("The new elements of the list are "+ numbers);
```

Comment: What does your code do that you didn't expect? What should it do and what did it do instead?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Javadoc for java.util.List, `numbers.add(i,a)` inserts `a` at index `i`. You should use `numbers.set(i, a)` instead since you don't want to insert new elements but replace existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

numbers.add(i,a) don't replace the element at position i. It inserts a new element at that position, thus increasing the size of the numbers array. Use the method numbers.set(i,a) instead